# AngularJS Http Post does not return success

Tags: angularjs, rest

This is service for sending data to Rest which rest return StatusText = "OK"

```js
service.Login = function(username, password, callback) {
     var encodedString = 'username=' + encodeURIComponent(username) + '&password=' + encodeURIComponent(password);
     var baseUrl = "https://localhost:450/rest/";
     $http({
         method: 'POST',
         url: baseUrl + "dns/loginResource",
         data: encodedString,
         headers: {
             'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
         }
     }).then(function(response) {
         var data = response.statusText;
         console.log(data);
         callback(data);
     }, function(error) {
         var data = error.data;
         console.log(data);
         callback(response);
     });
```

End this is controller for handle with callback

```js
$scope.login = function() {
    alert("Scope'a girdi...");
    AuthenticationService.Login($scope.username, $scope.password, function(response) {
        if (response.success) {
            AuthenticationService.SetCredentials($scope.username, $scope.password);
            $location.path('/admin');
        } else {
            $scope.error = response.message;
            console.log("Response not success");
        }
    });
```

However, code neve enter success function.

Comment: Is it entering in failure function? If yes, what is the error?

Comment: There is no error. Backend return OK as a status Text and 200 as a status.

Comment: and yes it is entering failure function

Comment: 200 is a success, your code is not failing

Comment: `var data = response.statusText;` should be `var data = response.data;`

Comment: in callback you are passing `callback(response.statusText);` but you are expecting `function(response)` and on response you are expecting `response.status` thats not goona work, change it to `callback(response.data);`

Comment: tiona i think you are right. How can i fix this ** Dont work

Comment: Thanks. callback(response.data) was solved my problem

Answer (score 0):

Change your controller to

```
if (response) {
        AuthenticationService.SetCredentials($scope.username, $scope.password);
        $location.path('/admin');
    } else {
        $scope.error = response.message;
        console.log("Response not success");
    }
```

Since you are returning the status text you don't need to again check response.success